# How to get value of pressed button (jQuery UI button-checkboxes)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, button, checkbox

Hello like in topic how get value(text) from checked buttons ?
Here is my example:

```
<div id="wyposazenie" style="display: table-row">
    <label>Wyposażenie dodatkowe:</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check1" /><label for="check1">Projektor</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check2" /><label for="check2">Odtwarzacz CD</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check3" /><label for="check3">Inne</label>
</div>
```

how get example value "Projektor" when button #check1 is checked ? And how get more than one value if checked more than one button

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) for this:

```
var arr = $("#wyposazenie :checkbox:checked").map(function() {
            return $(this).next().text();
          }).get();
```

Just run this whenever you need, it'll get an array of all the checked `<input>` elements' labels.